# What are the products A and B in the following reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

> What are the products A and B in the following reaction?
>
> [image: reactions scheme]

According to me, the $\ce{NH2^-}$ anion being a strong base would form an alkoxide ion. But since there are 3 $\ce{OH}$ groups it will form the most stable alkoxide ion and since a primary alkoxide ion is most stable the alkoxide ion will be formed at the $\ce{-CH2OH}$ site. This ion will undergo a nucleophilic substitution reaction forming an ether. But this is not the correct answer. If anyone could point out where I am wrong, please?

According to the textbook the correct structure of compound B is

[image: 3‐hydroxy‐5‐(hydroxymethyl)‐3‐methylcyclohexan‐1‐one]

Comment: I wonder why do you think that primary alkoxides are most stable.

Comment: @mykhal Since secondary and teritary have more alkyl groups attached to the alpha carbon.Alkyl grps are electron releasing in nature and thus will increase the electron density on the negative oxygen atom and thus making it unstable

Comment: Such differences are minor. In practice I doubt there would be much selectivity over which alkoxide is formed

Comment: @Waylander But in any case ether will be formed at one of the sites.As far as I know Kmno4 would not affect ethers.So Product B will have am ether group .But none of the options of this question satisfy this condition

Comment: I think there is an error in your textbook. MeI is going to react with any alkoxide to give a methyl ether, and you are correct that KMnO4 does not react with ethers, so there has to an ether in the product.  I am already suspicious of the quality of a textbook that suggests that there will be any selectivity in the formation of the Methyl ether.

Comment: @Waylander For some curiosity, I looked up for the starting material in the OP, and the suggested product B from the OP.  Yet both appear as unknown (so far) to Reaxys, and CA ...

Comment: @Waylander Thanks for clearing this thing up.Mistakes like these are very annoying because I will always think that I am missing something.